# How to filter salt modules usage

Tags: salt-stack

Is anyone aware of a way to filter salt modules usage per host/group/etc. Is there a way to filter it like salt pillar's `top.sls`?

For example I have module to manage haproxy which is depends on `haproxyctl` and thats only require to run on host with haproxy role.

Comment: you can use 'saltenv' to separate out

Comment: Pratik Anand, that's not clear how 'saltenv' can help with that and which mechanism should I use to filter modules

Comment: you can create different environments like backend, frontend, proxy etc, using you can differentiate it

Comment: Can you please clarify your use case? Do you want to run specific salt module from master via `salt` cli only on the nodes with specific roles?

Comment: @alexK yes, I have a set of haproxy hosts and I have salt module for custom haproxy actions with dependency to python's 'haproxyctl' and I need that module to be used only on that group of hosts

Answer (score 0):

If your roles are assigned in minion configuration - then they are available for your `salt` command as a regular grains.

E.g. if you have a minion configuration like:

```
<some config here>
grains: 
  roles:
    - haproxy
```

You can use the following command to execute state only on the nodes with `haproxy` role:

```
salt -C 'G@roles:haproxy' <your state here>
```

basically, with syntax `salt - C 'G@<grain>'` you can match on any grain.

Comment: Hi @alexK, Thanks for your reply but that's not about matching minions by compound mode or something like that. I'm looking for something like top.sls in root salt-states but for modules. Image the following, you have a module to control haproxy, salt module is a python file with have something like `import haproxyctl` and this module is propagated by salt on all nodes but I dont have haproxy, and haproxyctl on all my VMs.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what's the problem. If the module is being propagated to your minion, but you never call it with salt why is that a problem?
Can you maybe provide some more specific examples with code snippets and mention what exactly doesn't work?